# python error "ValueError: Invalid vertices array"

Tags: python, scatter-plot

I'm running the following code and get the following error for making the plot. When I print the cov variable, the numbers in it have single quotes around them. I'm assuming this is the problem? When I try to plot x and y, it works just fine. I'm a new python user. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
#!/bin/python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np
from sys import argv
#from numpy import array

#array = numpy.float64(array)

script, filename = argv

file = open(filename)

pos = []
cov = []

for line in file:
    if (line.split()[0])=='1':
        ch = int(line.split()[0])
        #adjpos = int(line.split()[1])
        pos.append(line.split()[1])
        cov.append(line.split()[2])

file.close()

print cov

x = [0, 1, 2, 3]
y = [5, 10, 5, 5]

print x
print y

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,3),edgecolor='w')
plt.scatter(pos,cov,marker='.',s=1)
plt.show()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eflannery/Dropbox/plotSamFlags.py", line 37, in <module>
    plt.scatter(pos,cov,marker='.',s=1)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2557, in scatter
    ret = ax.scatter(x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, faceted, verts, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axes.py", line 5876, in scatter
    self.add_collection(collection)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axes.py", line 1445, in add_collection
    self.update_datalim(collection.get_datalim(self.transData))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/collections.py", line 160, in get_datalim
    offsets = transOffset.transform_non_affine(offsets)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 1925, in transform_non_affine
    self._a.transform(points))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 1415, in transform
    return affine_transform(points, mtx)
ValueError: Invalid vertices array.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers need to be converted to a type that matplotlib can use; right now it just makes a list of strings, as `split()` returns a list of strings. You can fix this by calling `int()` (or `float()`, if the numbers aren't all integers) to convert the strings when you read the file, which you already did in the assignment to `ch`:

```
for line in file:
    if (line.split()[0])=='1':
        ch = int(line.split()[0])
        pos.append(int(line.split()[1]))
        cov.append(int(line.split()[2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers have quotes around them it means they are coming out at strings, which is likely causing the issue.

In your code here

```
         pos.append(line.split()[1])
         cov.append(line.split()[2])
```

This will append the numbers as strings to the lists pos and cov, so you should do what you did above and convert them to numbers.

```
         pos.append(int(line.split()[1]))
```

Comment: `float` instead of `int` would be safer in case there are floating point numbers in the text file.